# Ode solving in python with 2 second derivative terms per equation

Tags: python, matlab, ode

everyone

I've been working with a simple 2 DoF aeroelastic model, with the following ODE system:

```
m*h'' + S*alpha'' + k_h*h = L(t)
S*h'' + I*alpha'' + k_alpha*alpha = M(t)
```

with ' denoting the derivative in respect to the time t and the displacement h and the angle alpha being the variables.

I am used to work in matlab, in which I could just define the functions in terms of the second derivatives of h and alpha, such as in the code below:

```
function dYdt = ode(t, y, m, I, S, k_h, k_alpha, L, M)

   % h = y(1);
   % derivative of h = y(2);
   % second derivative of h = dYdt(2);
   % alpha = y(3);
   % derivative of alpha = y(4);
   % second derivative of alpha = dYdt(4);

   dYdt(1) = y(2);
   dYdt(2) = (L - k_h*y(1) - S*dYdt(4))/m;
   dYdt(3) = y(4);
   dYdt(4) = (M - k_alpha*y(3) - S*dYdt(2))/I;

end
```

Thus, I just defined dYdt(2) as a function of dYdt(4) and vice versa.

Lately, I've been trying to get more familiarized with python and trying to test old matlab codes such as this, but I've been having some trouble with this second derivatives. I've done this python function belows, in the same logic as I did in matlab:

```
def ode(t, y, m, I, S, k_h, k_alpha, L, M):
   # h = h
   # derivative of h = hd
   # second derivative of h = hdd
   # alpha = alpha
   # derivative of alpha = alphad
   # second derivative of alpha = alphadd

   h, hd, alpha, alphad = y
   
   hdd = (L - k_h*h - S*alphadd)/m
   alphadd = (M - k_alpha*alpha - S*hdd)/I

   return [hd, hdd, alphad, alphadd]
```

With this code I end up having the following error message: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'alphadd' referenced before assignment".

I understand that the problem is that, once each equation is dependent of the second derivative of the other equation, declaring the system like this is kind "circular", but this is what I used to do in matlab and used to work well.

Can somebody help me?

I've tried to insert the expression of alphadd inside the hdd equation and vice versa, without success so far. Unfortunately I haven't found anything similar on the internet so far.

Comment: This is also wrong in the Matlab code. You have a linear system for the second derivatives, you have to solve it as such, this will not happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll take a look on my matlab codes to make sure, but strangely matlab works fine this way for me. I will solve the linear system for this simpler problem and compare the results. The problem is that the models I'm using for L(t) and M(t) are huge functions of terms including h'' and alpha'', and the full system have more variables which are also dependent on second derivatives, so it will be quite a work to solve for everything. But I appreciate the comment and I'll try to do this way.

Comment: Then the second derivative of the first equation is read as zero, which gives the wrong value. Array access beyond the currently existing array gives either a range check error, or returns a default value, most often zero.

Comment: @Gabriel: You need to heed the advice of Lutz. There is no way your MATLAB code above is correct and working well ... it is definitely wrong. You should double check your ode formulae to make sure you have that correct. If indeed you have both 2nd derivatives in both equations, then you will need to set up the matrix algebra to solve for these 2nd derivatives in terms of lower order derivatives and other terms and use that solution in your derivative function.

Comment: Thank you Lutz and James for all the help! I will follow you recommendations to correct my codes right. Good thing I asked here, so I can correct my mistakes.